# Declare a fixed or "unfixed" array, filled with default values

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, boolean, declaration

Say I have this array, in C#:

```
public bool[] MyArrayName = new bool[3] { false, false, false };
```

If I want to extend this, I have to change the number and add another bool to the end:

```
public bool[] MyArrayName = new bool[4] { false, false, false, false };
```

It could get unmanageable and very ugly code really fast.
Ideally I want to declare it like this:

```
public bool[] MyArrayName = new bool[] {false};
```

But that's not possible... I just want a simple array of default values, that has a reasonable size. What's the best practice?

Comment: To declare an array of bools with the default value `false` you do NOT need to specify all the values. Your first example can be written like `public bool[] MyArrayName = new bool[3];`. You only need to specify the values if they are *not* the default `false` value. You will need to specify the size, of course - the compiler needs to know how big to make the array!

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense and works. How about a string array with a particular "default" string? Is the only way to use a for loop?

Comment: If you want to create a string array with N copies of string S, you can do it using Linq: `string[] array = Enumerable.Repeat(S, N).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a extend class to return an array with default value.

Like the following code:

```
 public static class Extend
    {
        public static T[] Arrwithdefault<T>(this T[] arr, T defaultvalue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = defaultvalue;
            }
            return arr;
        }

    }
```

Then, we can call the method in the following code:

```
    string[] arr1 = new string[3] ;
    string value1 = "test1";
    arr1 = Extend.Arrwithdefault<string>(arr1,value1);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr1[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("*************************");
    bool[] arr2 = new bool[5];
    bool value2 = false;
    arr2 = Extend.Arrwithdefault<bool>(arr2, value2);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr2[i]);
    }
```

Tested result:

[image]